# Laravel seeding via SQL file

Tags: php, sql, laravel, seeding

I'm trying to read data from a .sql file in a seeder to fill 3-4 tables with some data and DatabaseSeeder.php looks like this

```
public function run() {
    $this->call([
        UsersTableSeeder::class,
        // Bunch of seeders using Eloquent
        SqlSeeder::class
    ]);
}
```

All other seeders execute and, actually, when trying to throw an exception in SqlSeeder.php I'm able to stop the seeding. However, SqlSeeder.php won't seed the database via `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`, seems like it's bypassed. I always need to run `php artisan db:seed --class SqlSeeder` after, in order to make it seed the database. SqlSeeder.php looks like this

```
public function run() {
    $path = base_path().'/database/seeds/sql/data.sql';
    $sql = file_get_contents($path);
    DB::unprepared($sql);
}
```

Why's that?

Comment: check if all tables that seed from sql are empty after `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

Comment: What's the result of `dd(DB::unprepared($sql));`?

Comment: Solution: the .sql file was encapsulated into a transaction. Oddly enough, transactions and DB::unprepared() do not get along when calling php artisan migrate:refresh --seed but works when calling --class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own issue by removing transactions from the .sql file I was trying to execute via `DB::unprepared()`. Oddly enough, transactions completely fail when executing `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`, but they work if I later call the SqlSeeder individually via `php artisan db:seed --class SqlSeeder`. There are no foreign key constraints for now and InnoDB was chosen as engine, just to be sure, but still transactions both fail and work depending on the command.

I guess it all depends on how `Illuminate\Database\Seeder::call` works and calls seeder classes internally, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check if seeding data in sql file is in right order.

For example if you have foreign key `category_id` that references to `categories.id` `posts` table will be empty without any errors when you use this sql file:

```
INSERT INTO posts (title, category_id) VALUES ('test', 1);
INSERT INTO categories (title) VALUES ('category');
```

You should seed categories first and only then posts.

Comment: I know about order of seeding and in fact I took care of that. After countless other tries, I've found out DB::unprepared() as well as DB::statement() cannot stand *transactions* when called from within DatabaseSeeder.php, but worked just fine, with transactions, if called via db:seed --class SqlSeeder.php. Don't know why, but it worked by removing the INSERT INTO statements from a transaction!

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5 all you have to do inside of your main seed file is:

`\DB::unprepared(\File::get(base_path('path/to/your/sql/file.sql')));`